# javascript setTimeout() is not working after few minutes and then it resolves without delay

Tags: javascript, settimeout, delay

I wrote a code for timer of 60 seconds but setTimeout() is executing properly for few minutes but after some time it is resolving the function but without delay and the function is getting resolved in each second.

Here, this.rateCardTimerText is init with zero in the first call.

Please provide any proper solution if available or is there any alternative way to achieve it then please also mention that.

```
onChangeTimerChangeInfinity() {

    let no = Number(this.rateCardTimerText)

    if (no >= 100) {
        no = 0
        this.getCurrencyList()
    }
    else {
        no += 1.66
    }

    this.rateCardTimerText = no
    this.forceUpdate()
    setTimeout(this.onChangeTimerChangeInfinity.bind(this), 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you clear out the previous setTimeout each time you run it, like so:

```
let intervalObj;

onChangeTimerChangeInfinity() {
    clearTimeout(intervalObj)
    let no = Number(this.rateCardTimerText)

    if (no >= 100) {
        no = 0
        this.getCurrencyList()
    }
    else {
        no += 1.66
    }

    this.rateCardTimerText = no
    this.forceUpdate()
    intervalObj = setTimeout(this.onChangeTimerChangeInfinity.bind(this), 1000)
}
```

Also, just as with the above `setInterval()` option, you may end up with code tripping over itself because you're forcing this thing to fire every second regardless. If `getCurrencyList()` or `forceUpdate()` are `async`, consider rewriting a second function as a promise, then something like:

```
let intervalObj;

onChangeTimerChangeInfinity() {
    clearTimeout(intervalObj)
    doAsyncStuffInPromise().then( () => {
       intervalObj = setTimeout(this.onChangeTimerChangeInfinity.bind(this), 1000)
    })
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval()` instead.

```
setInterval( () => onChangeTimerChangeInfinity, 1000);

onChangeTimerChangeInfinity() {

    let no = Number(this.rateCardTimerText);

    if (no >= 100) {
        no = 0;
        this.getCurrencyList();
    }
    else {
        no += 1.66;
    }

    this.rateCardTimerText = no;
    this.forceUpdate();
}
```

Comment: It looks to me, that as per the code in the question, the interval should start only after the function `onChangeTimerChangeInfinity` has been called. But your code will start the `onChangeTimerChangeInfinity` after 1 second any way. I guess that's not correct?

Comment: Yes, but in this case the user only has to replace the first call with the setInterval()-call. After this it's the same, but not solved unnecessarily with an recursive approach.